# java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.Long in R2DBC mysql model classes

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc-mysql

I use R2DBC MySQL driver in my Spring Webflux reactive web. And I try to execute table schema SQL script. But the script continuously cause errors.

First, I make 3 model classes.

**User.java**

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder 
@Table("blog_user") 
public class User {
     
    @Id
    @Column("user_id")
    private Long id;
    
    @Column
    private String username;
 
    @Column
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;
     
    @Column
    private String fullname;
    
    @Column
    private Integer role;
}
```

**Post.java**

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Table
public class Post {
 
    @Id
    @Column("post_id")
    private Long id;
    
    @Column
    private String title;
  
    @Column
    private String body;
        
    @Column("created_date")
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;
    
    @Column("user_id")
    private User user;
    
    @Column("posts")
    private Collection<Tag> tags;
}
```

**Tag.java**

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Table
public class Tag {
  
    @Id
    @Column("tag_id")
    private Long id;
    
    @Column
    private String body;
    
    @Column("created_date")
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;
    
    @Column("post_id")
    private Post post;
        
    @Column("user_id")
    private User user;
}
```

**schema.sql**

```
-- TABLE intialized.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tag;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS post;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS blog_user;


-- TABLE created.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blog_user (
    user_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(255),
    fullname VARCHAR(255),
    role SMALLINT CHECK (role IN (0, 1)),

    PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
    UNIQUE (username)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS post (
    post_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    body TEXT,
    created_date DATETIME(6) NOT NULL,
    user_id BIGINT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (post_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES blog_user (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tag(
    tag_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    body VARCHAR(255),
    created_date DATETIME(6) NOT NULL,
    post_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    user_id BIGINT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (tag_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES post (post_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES blog_user (user_id)
);
```

Below configuration method executes schema.sql.

**reactive web initializer method**

```
@Bean
ConnectionFactoryInitializer initializer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

        ConnectionFactoryInitializer initializer = new ConnectionFactoryInitializer();
        initializer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        
        ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        databasePopulator.addScripts(new ClassPathResource(schema.sql));
        initializer.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulator);


        return initializer;
}
```

However, initially executed schema.sql throws errors,

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2m2023-01-01T09:06:30.943+09:00[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m10464[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[actor-tcp-nio-3][0;39m [36mdev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.MySqlConnection    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m The server timezone is <???ѹα? ǥ?ؽ> that's unknown, trying to use system default timezone
[2m2023-01-01T09:06:30.945+09:00[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m10464[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[actor-tcp-nio-3][0;39m [36mdev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.MySqlConnection    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m The server timezone is <???ѹα? ǥ?ؽ> that's unknown, trying to use system default timezone
[2m2023-01-01T09:06:30.947+09:00[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m10464[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[actor-tcp-nio-3][0;39m [36mdev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.MySqlConnection    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m The server timezone is <???ѹα? ǥ?ؽ> that's unknown, trying to use system default timezone
[2m2023-01-01T09:06:30.948+09:00[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m10464[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[actor-tcp-nio-3][0;39m [36mdev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.MySqlConnection    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m The server timezone is <???ѹα? ǥ?ؽ> that's unknown, trying to use system default timezone
[2m2023-01-01T09:06:30.951+09:00[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m10464[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[actor-tcp-nio-3][0;39m [36mdev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.MySqlConnection    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m The server timezone is <???ѹα? ǥ?ؽ> that's unknown, trying to use system default timezone
[2m2023-01-01T09:06:30.953+09:00[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m10464[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[actor-tcp-nio-3][0;39m [36mdev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.MySqlConnection    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m The server timezone is <???ѹα? ǥ?ؽ> that's unknown, trying to use system default timezone
[2m2023-01-01T09:06:30.955+09:00[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m10464[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[actor-tcp-nio-3][0;39m [36mdev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.MySqlConnection    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m The server timezone is <???ѹα? ǥ?ؽ> that's unknown, trying to use system default timezone
[2m2023-01-01T09:06:30.974+09:00[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m10464[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'initializer' defined in class path resource [com/aaa/blog/wf/config/BlogWebFluxConfig.class]: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource [sql/spring-boot-mysql-schema.sql]: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tag
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1751) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915) ~[spring-context-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at com.aaa.blog.wf.SpringBlogWebFluxMySqlApplication.main(SpringBlogWebFluxMySqlApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
Caused by: org.springframework.r2dbc.connection.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource [sql/spring-boot-mysql-schema.sql]: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tag
    at org.springframework.r2dbc.connection.init.ScriptUtils.lambda$runStatement$9(ScriptUtils.java:571) ~[spring-r2dbc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:94) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoStreamCollector$StreamCollectorSubscriber.onError(MonoStreamCollector.java:149) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoStreamCollector$StreamCollectorSubscriber.onNext(MonoStreamCollector.java:126) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.tryEmit(FluxFlatMap.java:543) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:984) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1839) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at reactor.core.publisher.NextProcessor.tryEmitValue(NextProcessor.java:358) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at reactor.core.publisher.NextProcessor.onNext(NextProcessor.java:298) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.MySqlResult.lambda$null$3(MySqlResult.java:114) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.LambdaSubscriber.onNext(LambdaSubscriber.java:160) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxWindowPredicate$WindowFlux.drainRegular(FluxWindowPredicate.java:670) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxWindowPredicate$WindowFlux.drain(FluxWindowPredicate.java:748) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxWindowPredicate$WindowFlux.onNext(FluxWindowPredicate.java:790) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxWindowPredicate$WindowPredicateMain.onNext(FluxWindowPredicate.java:241) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandleFuseable.java:193) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.util.DiscardOnCancelSubscriber.onNext(DiscardOnCancelSubscriber.java:70) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:854) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:250) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandle.java:128) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:854) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.drain(EmitterProcessor.java:537) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.tryEmitNext(EmitterProcessor.java:343) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalManySink.emitNext(InternalManySink.java:27) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.onNext(EmitterProcessor.java:309) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.client.ReactorNettyClient$ResponseSink.next(ReactorNettyClient.java:340) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.client.ReactorNettyClient.lambda$new$0(ReactorNettyClient.java:103) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:185) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:292) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundNext(FluxReceive.java:401) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundNext(ChannelOperations.java:411) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:113) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.client.MessageDuplexCodec.handleDecoded(MessageDuplexCodec.java:187) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.client.MessageDuplexCodec.channelRead(MessageDuplexCodec.java:95) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346) ~[netty-codec-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:318) ~[netty-codec-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1373) ~[netty-handler-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1236) ~[netty-handler-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1285) ~[netty-handler-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:529) ~[netty-codec-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:468) ~[netty-codec-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290) ~[netty-codec-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1710) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at org.springframework.r2dbc.connection.init.ConnectionFactoryInitializer.execute(ConnectionFactoryInitializer.java:112) ~[spring-r2dbc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.r2dbc.connection.init.ConnectionFactoryInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(ConnectionFactoryInitializer.java:97) ~[spring-r2dbc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1797) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915) ~[spring-context-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
        at com.aaa.blog.wf.SpringBlogWebFluxMySqlApplication.main(SpringBlogWebFluxMySqlApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.Long (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.Long are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$summingLong$23(Collectors.java:699) ~[na:na]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoStreamCollector$StreamCollectorSubscriber.onNext(MonoStreamCollector.java:117) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    ... 67 common frames omitted
```

I think my reactive R2DBC model classes contains some errors. ClassCastException. But I have no idea what element has wrong class type. The printed error message show no code line number. I changed the id type of model class(User, Post, Tag) into Integer type, but the same errors are thrown.

Comment: Put a breakpoint where the cast is attempted and see if you can figure out what is happening by looking at values up the stack.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using https://github.com/mirromutth/r2dbc-mysql 0.8.x RELEASE and the latest Spring Boot 2.7 or Spring Boot 3.0.x, I think there is a compatibility issue between the R2dbc MySQL driver you are using and R2dbc SPI managed by Spring Boot.

In the latest Spring Boot 3.0, R2dbc SPI was updated to 1.0, which introduced several incompatible APIs since 0.8(r2dbc-mysql 0.8.x RELEASE is aligned with R2dbc SPI 0.8). **I have encountered similar exceptions when upgrading to R2dbc 0.9 and 1.0 but used driver version is incompatible**.

- Try to use the latest [MariaDB R2dbc Driver](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-r2dbc) to connect your MySQL
- Consider other database, eg. PostgreSQL or switch to MariaDB directly.

**Update(2023-5-23)**: In the latest Spring Boot 3.x, it includes [jasycn r2dbc mysql](https://github.com/jasync-sql/jasync-sql/tree/master/r2dbc-mysql) instead of the original [r2dbc mysql driver](https://github.com/mirromutth/r2dbc-mysql) which is not active and stick on the old R2dbc SPI 0.8.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using a recent version of Spring Boot and Spring Framework.

The issue's root cause is using r2dbc-spi:1.0.0, which requires `getRowsUpdated()` to return a Long, but you're using dev.miku:r2dbc-mysql:0.8.2, which returns an Integer.

I suggest switching to [`io.asyncer:r2dbc-mysql:1.0.0`](https://github.com/asyncer-io/r2dbc-mysql) which is official successor to `dev.miku:r2dbc-mysql`. for more information see the [Deprecation NEWS](https://github.com/mirromutth/r2dbc-mysql/issues/251)

Answer (score 0):

Helped for me change dependency from

```
implementation("org.postgresql:r2dbc-postgresql:1.0.0.RELEASE")
```

to

```
implementation("io.r2dbc:r2dbc-postgresql:0.8.13.RELEASE")
```

for springboot 2.7.6

Thanks to Hantsy.

Comment: this one still does not work for springboot 3 and kotlin: first has Long to Integer cast exception on delete query, second does not perform the delete right even though handles Integer properly

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on delete operations with latest kotlin: 1.8.10, spring-boot: 3.0.4, r2dbc-spi: 1.0.0.RELEASE, r2dbc-postgresql: 1.0.1.RELEASE and jooq: 3.17.8.

It is interesting to note that the same code worked in coroutine style, when I converted jooq r2dbc publishers to suspend function with awaitSingle() method. But it failed in reactor mode.

Nevertheless the issue was resolved by updating jooq version to 3.18.0.

Answer (score 0):

The compatibility now seems to be documented and can be found here https://github.com/asyncer-io/r2dbc-mysql#spring-framework-and-r2dbc-spi-compatibility